# cannot find app.module.ngfactory, ionic error

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework

I have a problem that has been a pain in my .... when I type ionic serve --lab i get this error

```
typescript: C:/Users/ashley/hoof-app/src/app/main.prod.ts, line: 4
        Cannot find module './app.module.ngfactory'.

   L4:  import { AppModuleNgFactory } from './app.module.ngfactory';


at BuildError.Error (native)
at new BuildError (project\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\util\errors.js:16:28)
at Timeout._onTimeout (project\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\watch.js:71:20)
at ontimeout (timers.js:386:11)
at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5) hasBeenLogged: false, isFatal: false
```

I cannot seem to find anything that fixes this problem. here is my info, if you can help please give me an answer! I need to get this fixed. I am new to ionic and node.js so that's why I am having problems.

```
Ionic Framework: 2.0.0 
Ionic Native: 2.4.1 
Ionic App Scripts: 3.0.0 
Angular Core: 2.1.1 
Angular Compiler CLI: 2.1.1 
Node: 6.11.3 
OS Platform: Windows 10 
Navigator Platform: Win32 
User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:56.0) Gecko/
```

Thank guys

Comment: You need to either upgrade your ionic-framework to a newer version or downgrade ionic-app-scripts to a lower version. You are currently using ionic-app-scripts version 3.0.0 which expects an `app.module.ts` to be present.

Comment: @David  Thanks, that fixed that error, now I am getting this : expected expression, got '<'. I downgraded to app-script 2.0.0

Comment: Can't help you with that, you have to check where the error is thrown.